# How to avoid "unstyled" app during ECS deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, webpack, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

My express application is running in an amazon ECS container behind an ALB load balancer.

For cachebusting webpack generates a new hash each time the app is built and released and appends it to the CSS file name (e.g. `main.b938eb5b2934c85d13e0.css`).

During deployment of a new release, both containers (old version and new version) are running at the same time for about a minute and the LB routes requests to one of the containers randomly.

It then sometimes happens that users get the `index.html` from the new container, but the following CSS request is routed to the old container, resulting in 404 because the hash part of the filename is different. Users then see a completely broken unstyled GUI.

How can this be avoided this without losing the cachebusting aspect?

Comment: That's an interesting problem. How about establishing [sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html) for the duration of the deployment?

Comment: Interesting idea! Your link points to the "classic" load balancer, but the ALB also supports stickiness on the target group level. [Documenteation is here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions). I guess it will not solve the problem completely, it might still happen that a stickiness cookie expires while a release is being deployed. But it should reduce the number of users affected significantly. I'm going to give this a try today!